# Erro "Decode error - output not utf-8" no Sublime Text

Tags: java, sublime-text-2

Já olhei em **vários** sites, **várias** perguntas (inclusive no próprio stackoverflow) pesquisei muito mesmo e não consegui tirar ainda esse erro do Sublime Text 2:

> [Decode error - output not utf-8]

A Linguagem Em Questão É O Java, já tentei usar um .bat para compilar e executar o java, já tentei colocar "encoding": "utf-8" no JavaC.sublime-build, já tentei ir em file->Save with Encoding->UTF-8. O meu JDK ta certinho na variável `PATH`, eu tenho uma variável chamada `JAVA_HOME` com valor (C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\bin).

O meu JavaC.sublime-build atualmente está assim como é normalmente:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Mudei o JavaC.sublime-build:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name"], <- De "$file" para "$file_name"
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Agora ele ta compilando sem nenhum erro mas quando eu coloquei:

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac", "$file_name"],
    "cmd": ["java", "$file_base_name"], <- Adicionei Está Linha
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

Ele deu novamente o erro [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Traduzindo, por enquanto só consigo gerar .class, mas meu propósito é gerar o .class e executa-ló também.

Comment: Se você abrir ele com outro editor (ex: Notepad++), você consegue ver qual é o encoding?

Comment: @Victor Eu Abri O Notepad++ E Fui Em Formatar E Estava "Codificação em UTF-8 (Sem BOM)", Mas Isso É O Uma Coisa Padrão Do Notepad++ Ou É Realmente A Codificação Do Arquivo ?

Comment: @Victor E Também Vc Quer Que Eu Abra O Que No Notepad++ ? O JavaC.sublime-build ? Se For Ele, O Que Eu Disse Acima Está Certo !!

Comment: Não existe algoritmo que determine com exatidão a codificação do arquivo (o motivo é que imagine um arquivo vazio ou com apenas uma única letra 'a', como você sabe se isso é ASCII ou UTF-8?). O que estes programas fazem é tentar verificar qual é a codificação que faz mais sentido.

Comment: Acho que o JavaC.sublime-build não é a resposta. Bem amigo, sinto muito, mas não tenho ideia de como posso te ajudar. Fica com o meu +1 na sua questão, e boa sorte. Se eu tiver alguma ideia, eu volto aqui. :)

Comment: Blz, Obrigado (:

Answer (score 1):

```
"shell": true
```

Essa é a chave.

Se eu tentar um *build system* assim (no Win XP):

```
{
"cmd": ["ant", "-f", "project-build.xml"],
"working_dir": "${project_path}"
}
```

Me dá:

> [Decode error - output not utf-8]

Isso porque `cmd` devia ser `"ant.bat"`. O Sublime está procurando um arquivo cujo nome seja exatamente `ant`, e a codificação da mensagem `"file does not exist"` não é UTF-8. Se usar o shell assim:

```
{
"cmd": ["ant", "-f", "project-build.xml"],
"working_dir": "${project_path}",
"shell": true
}
```

tudo funciona (mesmo sem `"windows": { "cmd": ....}`porque o shell procura por `ant.exe` e depois por `ant.bat`.

Answer (score 0):

Veja se o seu editor tem opção de mudar o caracterset do texto, provavelmente está em cp1252, passe para UTF-8 (no eclipse clicando com o botão direito na arvore do projeto), pelo Notepad++, no menu superior "Formatar >> converter para UTF-8"

Eu sempre trabalho com fontes no UTF-8 o cp1252 dá muitos problemas.

Answer (score 0):

No meu caso resolvi renomeando a pasta que contém o arquivo. Deixando apenas um nome, sem pontos, vírgulas ou espaços. Espero ter ajudado.