# Sublime text com exit code 1. Como resolver

Tags: c, compilação, sublime-text-2

Estou com este **ERRO** ao tentar compilar qualquer código em `C` no meu **PC**:

```
[Decode error - output not utf-8]
[Finished in 0.2s with exit code 1]
```

Eu instalei o `MinGW` e os módulos `gcc(C++ e C)`, mas mesmo assim dá-me este erro, apesar de a única coisa que os códigos fazem é mostrar-me números. Alguém me pode ajudar?

Comment: Boa noite, o que o sublime-text-2 tem haver com o teu código? Edite a pergunta e coloque o código, se não fica dificil ajudar.

Comment: Olá. Se esse é um problema específico do Sublime, receio que esse não é o lugar certo para essa pergunta.

Comment: @Pablo certo é, mas não tem nada haver com compilar `C`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente o seguinte salvar seu arquivo C com a codificação certa, o sublime assume que a codificação dos arquivos na saída é UTF-8.

File->Save with encoding->UTF-8

É possivel editar o arquivo .sublime-build para aceitar outras codificações.

Veja:

- https://gist.github.com/clijiac/2814161
- [Erro "Decode error - output not utf-8" no Sublime Text](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42365/erro-decode-error-output-not-utf-8-no-sublime-text)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21068832/sass-on-sublime-text-3-decode-error-output-not-utf-8
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22598005/sublime-text-3-python-3-and-utf-8-dont-like-each-other
- https://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=7809

Outra possibilidade é que está faltando adicionar o diretório do compilador no PATH do windows.

Painel de Controle > Sistema e Segurança > Sistema > Configurações avançadas do sistema

Clique em Variáveis de Ambiente para ter a opção de incluir o caminho à variável PATH do usuário ou do sistema.

Comment: O último passo, o da variável, já tinha feito e ficou igual. E o de salvar como UTF-8 também. Tentei o método de alterar o sublime-build e deu-me o erro [Finished in 10.8s with exit code 1] na consola do programa eo erro: "cc1plus.exe" (titulo do erro), ..."zlib1.dll está em falta"... .